# Какой механизм использует Viber для показа сообщения поверх других приложений?

Tags: android

Сижу, например, в скайпе... И тут приходит сообщение вайбера поверх сайпа. 
Или даже экран телефона погашен, всё равно окошко вайбера появиться...

Какой механизм используется?

Comment: Ответ надо проверить... В данном случае нужно немного времени...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не знаю как в Viber но такое можно сделать с помощью обычного `AlertDialog`

прописываете в манифесте разрешение на отображение системных окон

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

Для программной разблокировки нужно разрешение

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>`

Перед показом диалога ставите флаг окну

`dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`

И все.

Можете поиграться с этим примером

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            init();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        private void init(){
            handler.postDelayed(task, 10000);
        }

        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showDialog();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        };

        private void showDialog(){
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            lock.disableKeyguard();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Test");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Будете получать алерт каждые 10 сек в независимости запущено приложение или нет.

**Не оставляйте телефон с запущенным сервисом :-)**

Comment: Будет работать с заблокированным экраном?

Comment: Это уже другая история, перед показом вам программно нужно разблокировать экран, посмотрите у Viber разрешения. А вообще это не бест, представьте вы ложите тел в карман, приложение пушит, разблокирует и погнало наяривать. Сейчас если разблокировать тел то диалог это первое что вы увидите.

Comment: Но вайбер же работает по такому принципу... Как программно разблокировать экран?

Comment: Сколько такое стоит реализовать по деньгам?

Comment: добавил разблокировку

Comment: Встроил в приложенице - до конца не работает (( Поверх приложений появляется, но вот разблокировать телефон не может

Comment: Разрешение прописали?

Comment: Да... Компилирую для версии 2.3.3... Может быть из-за этого?

Comment: Все может быть, посмотрите мои редактирования, там есть еще два флага, попробуйте с ними

Comment: SorryForMyEnglish, Вы занимаетесь фрилансом? Необходимо ваш код немного довести до ума. Есть skype, icq?

Comment: Сорри, но времени нет