# Как сделать всплывающее окно как в WatsApp которое будет открыто поверх всех окон?

Tags: java, android

Поставили задачу, о которой никогда не слышал. Нужно сделать окно в приложении, чтобы оно открывалось поверх даже открыты приложений. Для примера WatsApp(я даже не знал что там такое есть). Открыта у меня прога например любая, мне написали что-то, и у меня выскакивает окно похожее на DialogFragment, Dialog, AlertDialod но я не знаю что это. вот [Видео](http://vk.com/video142681208_171190948). Я нашел советы, и попробовал сделать активити прозрачный и открывать его, а на нем обычный диалог. Работает, но проблема в том, что тогда и моя программа открывается, которая должна быть свернута. Как блин сделать это? кто сталкивался?

**Правка:** как теперь из этого диалога открыть активити?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443627/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-viber-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/443657#443657

Comment: именно то что меня интересует. Сейчас проверю

Comment: Да просто афигенннно!!!!! чувак ты секономил мой день! В 1 строку решил проблему! а я тут велосипед мудрил!

Comment: Вызовите главное активити вашего приложения из сервиса, так и открывайте