# Своя подсказка поверх чужого окна

Tags: android, activity

Доброго дня всем!
Может кто подсказать, как вот такое реализовать? Свою подсказку вывести поверх системного окна?

[image: Это у Hi-Locker`а увидел, надо бы такуюже вещь сделать..]

Это у Hi-Locker`а увидел, надо бы такуюже вещь сделать..

Благодарю.

Comment: Решено. Если кому еще пригодится, делается таким образом: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Answer (score 1):

Так не пойдет?

```
AlertDialog.Builder complete = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this);
    complete.setTitle("текст");
    complete.show();
```

Comment: Доброго дня. Пробовал такое (на основе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443627 ) Но диалог появляется **под** окнами с системными настрйоками. Когда окно закрываешь - тогда вот он диалог.. Поверх окна блокировки он тоже выскакивает, а поверх системного окна - нет.